# Google Maps markers dont produce Infowindow on Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox

The following works OK on IE and Chrome but not on Firefox (uptodate, 27.0.1).

The symptoms I see is that clicking on a marker sometimes correctly displays an infowindow and sometimes it does not - when it does not I see a white downward triangle appearing top left of the map level with the streetview icon and an "X" window close at the same level on the right.

Assistance in debugging this gratefully received.

My simplified code is shown below (it still displays the error):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Map Test</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <center>
  <div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 800px;"></div>
  </center>

  <script type="text/javascript">


      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("GET","MapTestData.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

    var speakers=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SPEAKER");

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.4050, -2),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i, address, desc, j, iconurl;
    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < speakers.length; i++) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("LAT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("LONG")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
                });

            marker.open = false;
            speakers[i].desc = '<p style="text-align:left"><b>';
            if (speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("EMAIL")[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
                speakers[i].desc += 'Email: <a href="mailto:'+speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("EMAIL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'">'+speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</a></b>';
            }
            else {
                speakers[i].desc +=speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</b>';
            };

            if (speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("TEL")[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
                speakers[i].desc += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Tel:</b> '+speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("TEL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            };

            for (j=0; j < speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("DISPLAY").length; j++) {
               speakers[i].desc += '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("DISPLAY")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
               };


            markerBounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("LAT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, speakers[i].getElementsByTagName("LONG")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
            map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                 return function() {
                     if (!marker.open) {
                        infowindow.setContent(speakers[i].desc);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        marker.open = true;
                        }
                     else {
                        infowindow.close();
                        marker.open = false;
                        }
                     }
            })(marker, i));


      };

  </script>
</body>
</html
```

The code works off the following (test) data:

```
<MPF>
  <SPEAKERS>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person A</NAME>
    <PLACE>Ryton</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.36563</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.433982</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>No</MEAL>
    <PETROL>No</PETROL>
    <AREA>40 miles</AREA>
    <DISTANCE>40</DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS>None</EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 1a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 1b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 1c</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person B</NAME>
    <PLACE>Nottingham</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.976153</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.141237</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>Coffee</MEAL>
    <PETROL>No</PETROL>
    <AREA>30-40 miles</AREA>
    <DISTANCE>30</DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS>By arrangement</EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 2a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 2b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 2c</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person C</NAME>
    <PLACE>Solihull</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.411811</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.77761</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA></AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS></EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 3a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 3b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 3c</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person D</NAME>
    <PLACE>Sutton Coldfield</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.570299</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.82407</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA></AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS></EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 4a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 4b</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person E</NAME>
    <PLACE>Sutton Coldfield</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.573</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.81</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA>30 miles</AREA>
    <DISTANCE>30</DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS></EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 5a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 5b</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person F</NAME>
    <PLACE>Hereford</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.0598132</LAT>
    <LONG>-2.682874</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR>Yes</CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA>By arrangement</AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS>None</EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 6a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 6b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 6c</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person G</NAME>
    <PLACE>Malvern</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.106032</LAT>
    <LONG>-2.318292</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>No</MEAL>
    <PETROL>Half cost</PETROL>
    <AREA>None</AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS>None</EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 7a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 7b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 7c</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person H</NAME>
    <PLACE>Sutton Coldfield</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.565104</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.803349</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA>By arrangement</AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS>Daytime available</EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 8a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 8b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 8c</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 8d</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 8e</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 8f</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person I</NAME>
    <PLACE>Banbury</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.052179</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.352288</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR>By arrangement</CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA>By arrangement</AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS>By arrangement</EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 9a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 9b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 9c</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person J</NAME>
    <PLACE>Upton Snodsbury</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.18615</LAT>
    <LONG>-2.085697</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA></AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS></EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 10a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 10b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 10c</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person K</NAME>
    <PLACE>Tollerton</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.899822</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.097537</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA></AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS></EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 11a</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person L</NAME>
    <PLACE>Burton ?</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.814028</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.637136</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA></AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS></EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 12a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 12b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 12c</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 12d</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 12e</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 12f</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person M</NAME>
    <PLACE>Coventry</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.391121</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.498386</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL></MEAL>
    <PETROL>By arrangement</PETROL>
    <AREA>By arrangement</AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS></EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 13a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 13b</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 13c</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>
  <SPEAKER>
    <NAME>Person N</NAME>
    <PLACE>Birmingham</PLACE>
    <LAT>52.404588</LAT>
    <LONG>-1.930753</LONG>
    <TEL></TEL>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <CAR></CAR>
    <MEAL>By arrangement</MEAL>
    <PETROL></PETROL>
    <AREA></AREA>
    <DISTANCE></DISTANCE>
    <EVENINGS></EVENINGS>
    <DISPLAYS>
      <DISPLAY>Display 14a</DISPLAY>
      <DISPLAY>Display 14b</DISPLAY>
    </DISPLAYS>
  </SPEAKER>

 </SPEAKERS>
</MPF>
```

Comment: After `xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;` xmlDoc is `null`. It needs some time to read data.

Comment: `xmlDoc` is not null if line `xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML` is changed to `xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;`

Comment: @Anto Jurković: it's a synchronous request

Comment: FF shows this error in the javascript console: `Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_markersInfowindowsXml.html :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 37"  data: no]`

Comment: @Dr.Molle: I've forgot to write that I changed the code to read response `onreadystatechange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This may be a bug in Mozillas garbage-collection.**

Try that code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

  console.log('create click-function:',
              i,
              speakers[i].nodeName,
              typeof speakers[i].desc);

  var reference=speakers[i];

  return function() {
    if (!marker.open) {
      console.log('run click-function:',
                   i,
                   speakers[i].nodeName,
                   typeof speakers[i].desc);
      //(reference===speakers[i])//<!--note this line, uncomment it later
      infowindow.setContent(speakers[i].desc);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      marker.open = true;
    }
    else {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.open = false;
    }
  }
})(marker, i));
```

The log will show you that `speakers[i].desc` is available when you create the function, but when you run the function by clicking on the marker and the InfoWindow doesn't open `speakers[i].desc` is `undefined` (that's the reason why the infowindow doesn't open). the `<SPEAKER/>` is still available, but the `desc`-property oddly is missing.

Note this line:

```
var reference=speakers[i];
```

It only creates a reference to the particular speaker-node(but currently didn't use it)

now uncomment  the commented line:

```
(reference===speakers[i])
```

The reference to the node will be used now(not to set anything, only for  a comparision)

As you may note now all infowindows open.

The only reasonable explanation (for me) could be that now the behaviour of the garbage-collection changes, firefox recognizes that there is a reference to the node will be used. But such a reference will also be used inside the click-callback without that via  `speakers[i].desc` ,  it shouldn't make a difference.

There are a lot of workarounds/fixes. I would prefer to store  the infowindow-content as a property of the marker.